# POSIXct times around DST?

Tags: r, dst, date-arithmetic, posixct

I want to subtract 1 day from a POSIX date and end up at the same time around DST.

For example, when I add a day:

```
> as.POSIXct('2009-03-08 23:00:00.000') + 86400
[1] "2009-03-09 23:00:00 EDT"
```

But when I go past, it offsets:

```
> as.POSIXct('2009-03-08 23:00:00.000') - 86400
[1] "2009-03-07 22:00:00 EST"
```

What's the best way to deal with absolute time differences around DST?  Usually I deal with this by converting the times into strings and dealing with them separately so that DST isn't applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is doing exactly what you asked it to do, because you didn't ask it to add or subtract one day, you asked it to add or subtract *24 hours*. 24 hours (86400 seconds) before `2009-03-08 23:00:00 EDT` *is* `2009-03-07 22:00:00 EST`. I'm not familiar with the R libraries, but I am familiar with the POSIX functions that they wrap. If you take a POSIXct, decrease its `day` property by 1, and then "re-cast" it to `POSIXct` via `POSIXlt` ( to ensure that e.g. February -1st becomes January 31st) then you should be able to subtract one day reliably.

Answer (score 1):

Store datetimes as UTC - or in this case convert to UTC subtract a day and convert back to local time. (This ignores leap seconds)

Comment: If I convert to UTC, subtract a day, and then convert back, I will end up with the same offset because DST is still applied in the conversion.  Right?

Comment: Well depends on the acual dates if on the first day of DST then no otherwise yes.

But think of all date times as UTC and only format into local time at the last moment

Answer (score 1):

Thanks hobbs!  I need to do a little more work with it, but subtracting from the day slot works in POSIXlt:

```
> a <- as.POSIXct('2009-03-08 23:00:00.000')
> as.POSIXlt(a)
[1] "2009-03-08 23:00:00 EDT"
> a <- as.POSIXlt(a)
> a$mday <- a$mday -1
> a
[1] "2009-03-07 23:00:00 EDT"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the days, you can use `trunc` to just move the day:

```
> trunc(Sys.time(), "day") + 86400
[1] "2009-09-13 PDT"
> trunc(Sys.time(), "day") - 86400
[1] "2009-09-11 PDT"
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `lubridate` provides two additional timespan classes that specify what is somewhat unclear in the base package. From tha manual:

Durations

Durations measure the exact amount of time that occurs between two instants. This can create unexpected results in relation to clock times if a leap second, leap year, or change in daylight savings time (DST) occurs in the interval.

Periods

Periods measure the change in clock time that occurs between two instants. Periods provide robust predictions of clock time in the presence of leap seconds, leap years, and changes in DST.