# Possible bug in `difftime` - calculating difference in date time in R

Tags: r, dst, date-arithmetic, posixct, difftime

I am calculating differences in two date times, using the `difftime` function in `R` and getting a wrong answer, here is the code

```
t1 <- as.POSIXct("7/18/2005 8:30:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
t2 <- as.POSIXct("10/30/2005 8:30:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
difftime(t2,t1,units = "hours")
```

I am getting the following answer

```
Time difference of 2497 hours
```

which I know is wrong, as both `t1` and `t2` have the same `time` value, so they should be separated by an exact multiple of 24 hours (i.e., the correct answer is 2496 hours, not 2497 - also confirmed by other tools such as excel, google sheets).

Any idea, why `R` is giving me the wrong result?

Comment: You gained an hour due to Daylight Savings Time changeover on Sunday 10/30/2005 02:00:00. You can see the difference is 25h between 10/29/2005 and 10/30/2005

Comment: @smci is correct. using `tz="UTC"` will fix the problem.

Comment: It's not necessarily wrong, it depends what timezone this is supposed to be. But UTC makes things unambiguous.

Comment: @smci, thanks! That was a subtle mistake in my code!!

Comment: Related: [POSIXct times around DST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395499/posixct-times-around-dst) and there are [213 questions about \[r\] DST](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+DST). This is probably a duplicate

Comment: Reminds me of riddles like *"Where did the plane go for the missing hour?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gained an hour due to Daylight Savings Time changeover (Sunday 10/30/2005 02:00:00)

You can modify this by doing `as.POSIXct(..., tz = 'UTC')` with whatever timezone it's supposed to be; UTC to make things unambiguous and avoid DST changes.

If you want to modify the default timezone for all `as.POSIXct()` calls, see [How to change the default time zone in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374874/how-to-change-the-default-time-zone-in-r), which suggests:

- [as an R command] `Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')` or
- [R setup file] edit `TZ="UTC"`into `Renviron.site`